# Why does the equivalence between the algebraic and geometric definitions of dot product relies on having a orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I do not get why they are only equivalent when we are working with a orthonormal basis, is the algebraic definition defined only for those basis? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

That’s basically it. In a non-orthonormal basis, the algebraic expression for the Euclidean scalar product—the geometric definition—also involves mixed terms, so it’s not a simple “dot product.” On the other hand, any two orthonormal bases are related via an orthogonal transformation matrix, and it’s pretty easy to show that the dot product is invariant under such transformations, so any orthonormal basis will do. Note, though, that there’s a bit of a circularity here because the notions of length and angle that are used in the geometric definition are tied to the choice of scalar product for the space.

Comment: Let's see if i got you.

In a non - orthonormal basis if I compute xu.xv + yu.yv + zu.zv  it wont be the same as the product of the two lengths by the angle  , the geometric definition will have to be corrected.

So is it ok to say that the algebraic definition is the fundamental definition of dot product? I mean, it doesn't change when we change the basis, what changes is the geometric definition

Thank you.

Comment: thinking once more I think that the lenghts and angles wont change by a change of basis, so that the fundamental definition here is the geometric one??

Comment: @VictorLuiz I’m trying to be careful to distinguish “dot product”—a particular algebraic operation on the components of a pair of $n$-tuples of numbers—from “inner product,” a bilinear function that takes a pair of vectors and spits out a scalar. The geometric notions of length and angle are connected with a specific inner product on the space and are indeed independent of the basis....

Comment: @VictorLuiz Relative to an orthonormal basis, this inner product can be expressed as a dot product, but in other bases, it will look like some other kind of quadratic form. However, in order to define “orthonormal,” you need to have first defined length and angle somehow, so in that sense the geometric definition is more fundamental. This fundamental definition runs into a chicken-and-egg situation: you can either start with some definition of length and angle and with those define the inner product, or you can start with an arbitrary inner product and define length and angle through *that*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start with a Euclidean plane. Pick an origin and two unit vectors from the origin. The projection of each vector on the other has length the cosine of the angle between them by using right triangles. The dot product is a bi-linear functional on two vectors. The geometric definition forces the dot product of two perpendicular vectors to be zero and of a unit vector with itself to be one, and this gives the algebraic definition.